3D plot of GAMM with a 4-way interaction
I am running a GAMM to test how the likelihood of a response variable varies according to a predictive variable, date, and geographical coordinates of each sampled point. For this, I built the following model with the mgcv package:
    gam(RespVar(binomial) ~ te(PredVar, Date, Longitud, Latitud, d=c(1,2,3,4) + s(Year, bs="re))

I managed to plot it with the draw function (gratia package), and I got a 4x4 grid of different spatial coordinates, and with variation of PredVar and date in the x and y axis respectively of each grid cell. But it is not super intuitive...
Ideally I would like to plot how RespVar changes depending on PredVar and date in each point I sampled within my study area, i.e. on a map. Is this possible?
I found other posts about creating 3D plots with 4 variables (e.g.here ), but could not find any on plotting models with 4 way interactions. I also tried plotly, and it works fine but I was thinking more of a surface that varies depending on the model results (like a spiky map).
Thanks!
